# Automatically add different numbers of days to a date depending on today's date

Tags: google-sheets

How do I create a formula to add 8 days to a date? For example, I want to add 8 days to 2/14/24 in one cell. Then, tomorrow, have the 2/15/24 date have 8 days added to it.

Answer (score 0):

## Variables

1. `startDate` - This is the first date to add 8 days to.
2. `today` - The current calendar date is required in order to understand if *"today"* is actually *"tomorrow"* or next week relative to the `startDate`. It is returned by the TODAY function.
3. `addToDate` - This is only required if different from the `startDate`

## Version 1

This version supports an `addToDate` that is different from the `startDate`

```
=IF(ISDATE(startDate)*ISDATE(addToDate),
    SEQUENCE(1, TODAY()-startDate+1, addToDate+8, 8),
    "Date Missing "&ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()-1, 4))
```

##### Version 1 Example in `B4`

- `TODAY() = 02/15/2024`

```
=IF(ISDATE(B1)*ISDATE(B2),
    SEQUENCE(1, TODAY()-B1+1, B2+8, 8),
    "Date Missing "&ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()-1, 4)))
```

[image: Version 1 screenshot]

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **startDate →** | 02/12/2024 |  |  |  |
| **2** | **addToDate →** | 02/15/2024 |  |  |  |
| **3** |  |  |  |  |  |
| **4** | **Formula →** | 02/23/2024 | 03/02/2024 | 03/10/2024 | 03/18/2024 |

## Version 2

This version assumes the `startDate` and `addToDate` are the same

```
=IF(ISDATE(startDate),
    SEQUENCE(1, TODAY()-startDate+1, startDate+8, 8),
    "Date Missing "&ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()-1,4))
```

##### Version 2 Example in `B4`

- `TODAY() = 02/15/2024`

```
=IF(ISDATE(B1),
    SEQUENCE(1, TODAY()-B1+1, B1+8, 8),
    "Date Missing "&ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()-1, 4))
```

[image: Version 2 screenshot]

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **startDate →** | 02/14/2024 |  |  |  |
| **2** |  |  |  |  |  |
| **3** |  |  |  |  |  |
| **4** | **Formula →** | 02/22/2024 | 03/01/2024 |  |  |